# A Bootstrap 4 navbar is vertical instead of horizontal?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to produce a horizontal pagination menu dynamically with PHP. This mostly works, and I'm using Bootstrap 4's Nav to organize it.

However, while the menu itself is correct, it outputs vertically instead of horizontal.

[image]

This is the code that outputs the menu. As far as I can tell, the code is correct. I am including it in case something might be off with the generator.

```
public function paginateList($Page = 1, $Limit = 15, $Route = '')
{
    $Count = $this->CoreImages->countImageTotal();
    $NumberOfPages = floor($Count / $Limit);
    $obj = "<nav class='navbar navbar-dark'>";
    $obj .= '<ul class="navbar-nav">';
    $obj .= "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='" .  $Route . '/1' . "'>" . 'First' . "</a></li>";
    for($i = 2; $i < $NumberOfPages; $i++) {
        $obj .= "<li class='nav-item'>";
        $obj .= "<a class='nav-link' href='" .  $Route . '/' . $i . "'>" .  $i . "</a>";
        $obj .= "</li>";
    }
    $obj .= "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='" .  $Route . '/' . $NumberOfPages . "'>" . 'Last' . "</a></li>";
    $obj .= '</ul>';
    $obj .= "</nav>";

    return $obj;
}
```

This is the actual output, run with an 'echo':

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-dark'>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>First</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>1</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/2'>2</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/3'>3</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/4'>Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What am I missing to get the orientation correct?

Comment: Why are you showing PHP code? This is related to the HTML, and is nothing to do with PHP. Just show us the end product.

Comment: I added the html, but it might still have something to do with the PHP and the way that the menu is formed, which controls the html.

Comment: Add the class `navbar-expand` to the `nav` element.

Comment: @miken32 - Your comment worked perfectly, could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap’s navbar is collapsed for mobile devices. This results in a vertical layout. You can add the `navbar-expand` class to expand it to a horizontal layout. This can be dependent on screen size as well, using typical Bootstrap method: for example `navbar-expand-lg`.

> Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` with `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you should use navs instead of navbar

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>First</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>1</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/2'>2</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/3'>3</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/4'>Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or if you want to use navbar Please look into their documentation. you are missing some components that are in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything Bootstrap 4 - simply change your nav bar class on your ul tag, to nav only. You can keep the navbar class on your nav tag - this adds additional padding.

```
<nav class='nav navbar navbar-dark'>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>First</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>1</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/2'>2</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/3'>3</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/4'>Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

To make your navbar horizontal you need to add some style(CSS) to it.There are two ways to do so.**First**, by using inline CSS and second by External CSS. In first way change your code from

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-dark'>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>First</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>1</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/2'>2</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/3'>3</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/4'>Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

to this one

```
 <nav class='navbar navbar-dark'>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class='nav-item' style="display:inline;"><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>First</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item' style="display:inline;"><a class='nav-link' href='/1'>1</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item' style="display:inline;"><a class='nav-link' href='/2'>2</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item' style="display:inline;"><a class='nav-link' href='/3'>3</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item' style="display:inline;"><a class='nav-link' href='/4'>Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the **Second way** is find nav-item class in your css file and update one more style to it i.e.

```
nav-item {
display: inline;
 }
```

From both ways the most preferred is the **Second Way** and you can follow the link also.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp